# Carry Around C Compiler

Tags: c, mobile

I'm aware that there are programable calculators but are there any calculator sized (prehaps bigger) devices that could compile C code?

Comment: an iphone.. or ANY smartphone

Comment: I had a look for iphone apps but they all had horrible reviews and were completly wrong

Comment: a netbook was a bit too big. Also I didn't know where else to ask this question so sorry for being off topic.

Comment: @JordanBrown a [Ubuntu-powered Android device](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android) or [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org) is probably your best bet.

Comment: As long as it has a big enough screen and can execute ssh, it should do it - I can certainly get to my computer from anywhere I have network access [although I don't think I'd like to actuallu write code on my Android phone].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost anything that has a decent sized processor (32-bit) and an operating system that gcc supports can be made to compile C/C++ etc  [listed here](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html). The tricky parts are:

1. You need enough storage to have sufficient libraries etc to make it worthwhile. (RAM may also be an issue in some cases, especially if you try to compile LARGE sections of code).
2. Getting the code onto the device - if you are just copying files over, then it's no big deal, but if you need to actually type code in, you will need a keyboard and a screen.

I personally prefer to use a device to log into my desktop over the internet. As long as you can convince the machine to run `ssh` or `putty` (which should work on a lot of things - I can do it on my feeble Android phone - there are versions of Windows phone, iphone and  Nokia/Symbian phones can do it too). Now you can compile code on your desktop machine from wherver you are...

Answer (score 2):

Haven't you heard of the [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/)?

Comment: no I haven't could you give me a summary. Also relevant: http://xkcd.com/1053/

Comment: Click on the FAQ section on their website.  First question in the introduction.

Comment: Kind of hard to use without a screen and a keyboard!! So, a pretty poor answer.

Comment: Um, it's not a poor answer.  He asked for a device that was portable and compiled C code.  My answer names that device.  Obviously you will have to have some sort of input and output for **any** device to be of any use to you, or it would be pretty useless.

Comment: A screen and keyboard are not portable. Or do you suggest that the Pi can be used without. Also your answer is quite rude. Please try to edit it to take away the implicit put-down.

Comment: My suggestion, if portability is of the essence, is [this](http://blog.parts-people.com/2012/12/20/mobile-raspberry-pi-computer-build-your-own-portable-rpi-to-go/).  And my comment was just a rebuttal from your comment, saying that my answer was poor; it was not intended to be rude.

Comment: using that device could you design it specificly for C compiling or at least have that ability?

Comment: Yes, it comes with software that will allow you to compile C code.